# What is array destruturing in `query[name_value[0]] = name_value[1];`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint

I am running [`eslint`](https://eslint.org/) against my JavaScript in one of my projects. Today it told me:

> error: Use array destructuring

The offending code looks like this:

```
query[name_value[0]] = name_value[1];
```

I have another statement that looks like this:

```
query[name_value[0]] = true;
```

And I don't get the error, so it looks like that *decay* would be happening on the right side.

I checked the docs about the [array or object desstructuring](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) and I have to say I don't understand what they see as being *wrong*.

Complete function, just in case:

```
var query = null;

function get_query_string(name)
{
    var url,
        location_query,
        query_array,
        idx,
        name_value;

    if(null === query)
    {
        url = String(window.location.href);
        location_query = url.split("?", 2);
        query_array = 2 == location_query.length
                         ? location_query[1].split("&")
                         : [];

        query = {};

        for(idx in query_array)
        {
            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(query_array, idx))
            {
                name_value = query_array[idx].split("=", 2);
                if(2 === name_value.length)
                {
                    query[name_value[0]] = name_value[1];  // offensive line
                }
                else
                {
                    query[name_value[0]] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return query[name];
}
```

---

**Update**

I now have it working right (at least in Firefox), I just changed the type of `query` to an object and the test at the top had to change too. That does not change the fact that the error about destructuring happens.

Comment: *I think* it depends on surrounding code you haven't shown

Comment: @JaromandaX I added the complete function. I have no clue whether additional lines of code would be required to explain that problem, but anyway, here it is.

Comment: it's like eslint expects you to write `let [key, value] = name_value = query_array[idx].split("=", 2);` then use `query[key] = value;` (I think) - though, that doesn't make sense if you need to check the length of the split array ... odd

Comment: Right, there may be no "=" sign in there... and that `let ...` syntax is ES6 which I prefer to avoid at this point.

Comment: Where does destructuring occur at code at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I marked the line as "offensive line".

Comment: That assignment is not destructuring

Comment: read the error message @guest271314 - eslint is telling the OP to use destructuring instead of his code

Comment: @JaromandaX Interesting. The code does not have an error though labels working code as an error. What is the purpose of using such a script? If anything the "error" should be labeled as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this change should remove the "error" (though, error seems harsh!)

```
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(query_array, idx))
        {
            let [key, value] = query_array[idx].split("=", 2);
            if(value !== undefined)
            {
                query[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                query[key] = true;
            }
        }
```

or even

```
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(query_array, idx))
        {
            let [key, value] = query_array[idx].split("=", 2);
            query[key] = value === undefined ? true : value;
        }
```

Comment: Well... as I mentioned in a comment, the `let ...` instruction is an ES6 feature which I am still trying to avoid. But the syntax works when I allow ES6 features. Now I wonder why they think destructuring is better than the _normal way_ of doing things...

Comment: you can use var instead ... then you would just use `[key, value] = ...`